# Optimize an iteration of IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a method called "MergeString" which takes an argument of IEnumerable string list. The method's job is to iterate through the list and merge the list into one big string and return it.

Is it possible to do this even faster than using a foreach loop like i already do?

The following code is a simple implementation of how to do the iteration with foreach loop.

```
    public static string MergeStrings(IEnumerable<string> strs)
    {

        var toReturn = "";

        foreach (var str in strs)
        {
            toReturn += str;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
```

The following code below is the main method which runs the code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filling array: ");

        var strs = Enumerable.Range(0, 40000).Select(s => s.ToString());


        var before = DateTime.Now;

        var output = StringHelpers.MergeStrings(strs);  

        var after = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine($"Length: {output.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + (after - before).TotalMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Just use string.join. it does exactly the same

Comment: The problem is that if we increase the range to e.g. Enumerable.Range(0, 100000) it will take up to 2+ seconds to merge all the strings. If we then increase it even more than that it is even slower.

Comment: Worth reading: [Do not concatenate strings inside loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms182272(v=vs.80))

Comment: It's up to the implementer of the IEnumerable to implement the fastest possible enumeration of the collection. If all you know about the collection is that it implements IEnumerable, then `foreach` is your friend. In your particular case, you may speed things up by using a `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation in your loop. Doing string concatenation in a loop is usually a bad idea